# Select form parameter passes through but cannot use Rails include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get

Ok Rails 4.2 simple stuff here....basic select tag multiple:

```
 <%= select_tag('status_ids', options_for_select(Status.to_a), :multiple => true,  :include_blank => true, :class => "form-control  js-example-basic-multiple") %>
```

HTML params =

```
    {"utf8"=>"✓","search_term"=>"","status_ids"=>["1", "2"],"commit"=>"Search"}
```

Now in the controller i can do a query like and it works fine

```
    x=searchresults.where(status_ids: params[:status_ids])
```

what i cannot do is this:

```
    if params[:status_ids].include?(2)
```

or

```
    if 2.in?(params[:status_ids])
```

i can do this in the console and return a => true 
but not in the controller

what is the issue here?

danke

Answer (score 0):

Because your status_ids are strings, not integers like in your comparison code. You need to convert them to integers first..

```
if params[:status_ids].map(:&to_i).include?(2)
```

Comment: you have the & and the : reversed    `if params[:status_ids].map(&:to_i).include?(2)`   seems to work for me